# Controlling external clock source with FPGA - clean signal needed

Tags: fpga, adc, clock

I'm working with an ADC that requires a non-continuous clock source. My FPGA clock is quite noisy, so I would prefer to use a external oscillator to clock the bits out of the ADC. The clock should be running for 300ns, and then disabled for 200ns. Since these are very small times, I don't think I'll be able to toggle the clock on/off using the enable pin due to the delay times (> 100ns).

If I use the oscillator as an input to my FPGA, and control the output internally, would the signal be much cleaner than just using the FPGA clock?

EDIT: I did not include the part number in the original post: [LTC2324](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/232416f.pdf)

Comment: Does your ADC work with a non-uniform clock?  A lot do not work well with sudden changes in clock input.  Assuming yours does, add an AND gate between your clock source and the ADC input and use that to enable/disable the clock.

Comment: Not sure why you say FPGA clock is noisy. It sounds like you need a slow clock of 2 MHz, you can forward that clock cleanly out of FPGAs (using ODDR if Xilinx).

Comment: The clock input is only for clocking out the converted bits, so if you gave it a uniform clock you would be reading garbage during the conversion. Here is the datasheet: https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/232416f.pdf

Comment: @MituRaj, 500ns is the not the clock period, but the "envelope period", that determines when the clock is running and disabled. The clock will be 110 MHz.

Comment: @hucklord - putting the part number and datasheet link in your original question would be very helpful. Also, where should we look in the datasheet about the uniform clock caveat?

Comment: You can attach the datasheet to the question. By the way, it looks like a source-synchronous SPI interface. You can generate the 2 MHz SCLK from FPGA only when you need to read the samples.

Comment: @ErikR good point, I added it now. It's a sneaky datasheet that doesn't explicitly state that clock needs to be non-uniform. Figure 21 has the timing diagrams relevant to me (SDR mode). The reason I'm sure about the non-uniform clocking is because someone has asked before me: https://ez.analog.com/data_converters/precision_adcs/f/q-a/98034/ltc2324-16-maximum-conversion-time

Comment: @MituRaj - the FPGA will definitely control the SCK input (110MHz, btw) to the ADC, but my question is whether it should generate the signal itself or just enable/disable the signal from an external oscillator.

Comment: One should never use a clock generated from an FPGA to clock a high-speed/high-precision ADC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are TWO clocks that matter to that device, CNV (specifically the falling edge) and sclk.

Sclk is gated, and runs typically at either 55 or 110MHz, but is not particularly jitter sensitive, so a clock capable FPGA pin or even a ODDR register with the inputs strapped appropriately should be just fine there.

CNV is the 2MHz one that matters for this thing because the falling edge switches from sample to hold on the ADC input stage.
If you look at the datasheet, they suggest slipping an external D type in to synchronise this with the main FPGA clock input, basically you want low jitter on the falling edge here.

The extent to which jitter matters here is HIGHLY dependent upon the frequency range of the input.

Comment: Thanks! I'm following that example circuit for the CNV input, and I think I'll use an external clock for everything. The FPGA will control the clock, but I don't trust it to generate a clean 110 MHz signal by itself, even if the SCK jitter isn't as critical as CNV.

Comment: The SCLK jitter is completely irrelevant as long as it stays within frequency specs.